# Error: Unable to access jarfile ERROR MESSAGE

Tags: java, bash, shell, jar, exec

I have a MyFolder folder with a "run" script and a .jar file to execute.

My script is this:

```
!/bin/bash
clear
java -jar ./PokerGame-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And insider the folder Myfolder I have:

```
Myfolder:
-PokerGame-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-PokerGame.iml
-pom.xml
-run
-src(folder)
-target(folder)
```

When I try to run the script, I always get this message:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile ./PokerGame-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am quite stuck, any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have execution/access rights to the jar file?

Comment: Put this in your script and add output to your question (no comment): `ls -l ./PokerGame-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 0):

You wrote an ./ in front of your jar file name. Since its execute via java you just need to change "java -jar ./PokerGame-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" into "java -jar PokerGame-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".

Sincerely, Jannis.